# Transforming a row-based JSON in a column-based JSON

Tags: javascript, json, row, transform

I would like to transform a row-based JSON in a column-based JSON. I receive the JSON in a row-based form and will do some visualization with it, which would be easier in a column-based form.

row-based would look something like this:

```
{
  "0": {
    "fname": "John", 
    "lname": "Miller", 
    "age": 50
  }, 
  "1": {
    "fname": "Eve", 
    "lname": "Johnson", 
    "age": 40
  }...
```

Example column-based:

```
{
  "fname": {
    "0" : "John", 
    "1" : "Eve"
  }, 
  "lname": {
    "0" : "Miller", 
    "1" : "Johnson"
  }, 
  "age": {
    "0": 50, 
    "1" : 40
  }...
```

Is there a more efficient way than just looping through all elements and rewriting the JSON completely?

Thanks!

Comment: The structure seems very strange. Why do you use an object with numerical properties instead of an array?

Comment: The numerical properties are just an example. I only wrote them down to emphasize the change between rows and columns. They are not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no better way other than looping through every object. As you need all the values to be mapped, you'll have to go through all the keys.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was hoping there might be a different way, but I will have to work with a loop then.

Comment: Welcome. You can accept this as answer. Once you are done implementing that function, make it publicly available as a library. Might be useful to some. :)

Answer (score 1):

At least, you need to swap the keys for the result object.

```js
var data = { 0: { fname: "John", lname: "Miller", age: 50 }, 1: { fname: "Eve", lname: "Johnson", age: 40 } },
    result = Object.keys(data).reduce(function (r, k) {
        Object.keys(data[k]).forEach(function (l) {
            r[l] = r[l] || {};
            r[l][k] = data[k][l];
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```